# iPhone UITabBarController question: How to change previous view of a tab upon return to that tab?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a simple way, when returning to the primary tab on a UITabBar, for one to swap out the view that was last displayed in that tab for a new one?  Would this be with the ViewDidAppear method?  How would I keep this from happening on the initial load?  Perhaps initialize a counter to control this?  Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the `UITabBarDelegate`'s `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method and replace the view there. You can use a `BOOL` to make the switch.